# Has ContinueWith()'s body a chance of being invoked before ContinueWith() returns the related Task?

Tags: c#, .net-core, task, task-parallel-library, captured-variable

I have a synchronized Task list populated, for monitoring purposes.
I want to progressively remove the completed tasks from the list. To do so I resolved to use Continuation tasks like so:

```
//remove createdTask from list on termination
Task self = null!;
OnGoingHandlers.Add(self = CreatedTask.ContinueWith(tsk => OnGoingHandlers.Remove(self)));
```

is there a chance for `OnGoingHandlers.Remove` to be called when `self` is still `null`?

-EDIT-
the complete context is:
I have an `HttpListener`.
The listener spawns one or more tasks based on the JSON content of the received message.
When I stop the listener, I want to know when all the task it spawned have completed.

The `OnGoingHandlers` is a [`SynchronizedCollection<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedcollection-1).

-EDIT2-
I avoided the issue changing it to:

```
member.OnGoingHandlers.Add(CreatedTask);
CreatedTask.ContinueWith(tsk => member.OnGoingHandlers.Remove(CreatedTask), TaskScheduler.Default);
```

but i am still curious about the behaviour of the one-line alternative.

Comment: As a side note, the `ContinueWith` usage inside the question violates the [CA2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) guideline about not creating tasks without passing a `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: I'd question if you are looking at the right abstraction. I guess you want to monitor progress of some kind of batch of operations?

Comment: @Fildor I've just started programming with C#, and need to familiarize with its constructs. I could probably use a completely different approach, but it's never bad to learn the inner workings of stuff :)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it is a SynchronizedCollection<Task>. It belongs to an extension package for system.collection.generics.  
  
about the guideline thank you for pointing it out! I don't know right now how TaskScheduler work, would a ```Task.Run(()=>await ...)  avoid the issue..?

Comment: Andrea Bardelli the recommendation is to use one of the `ContinueWith` overloads that has a `scheduler` parameter, and pass as argument the `TaskScheduler.Default` (usually).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a chance for `OnGoingHandlers.Remove` to be called when `self` is still `null`?

Yes, there is. This can happen in case the CPU is oversubscribed, and the Operating System (OS) decides to suspend the current thread just after the `CreatedTask.ContinueWith` call and before the `self =` assignment. Then while the current thread is suspended, the OS gives the green light to a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread to execute the continuation. The chances of this happening are pretty slim, which makes this [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) all the more nasty. It might happen once in a blue moon, resulting in a bug that nobody will be able to reproduce.

FYI the OS can suspend any thread at any time for a duration of a few milliseconds (according to [my measurements](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3kWlV6) up to 50 msec).

Comment: Note that there are multiple race conditions here.  Not only can `self` in the continuation be resolved before the assignment, leaving it null, but the removal in the continuation can happen before the add (regardless of what `self` resolves to), leaving the task permanently in the collection.  That error is much more likely.  Since the collection is synchronized, it's reasonably probable for some other thread to have a lock, resulting in the adding code being suspended for long enough for the continuation to run and attempt to add it.  So if the lock is contentious then the error is *likely*.

Comment: @Servy true. I just focused at answering the OP's question. The `SynchronizedCollection<T>.Remove` is a O(n) operation, which also increases the chances of `lock` contention.